# How to UNPIVOT to normalize output SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, unpivot

Is it possible to UNPIVOT data like this?

The columns CGL, CPL, EO  should become `Coverage Type`, the values for CGL, CPL, EO should go in column `Premium`, and values for CGLTria,CPLTria,EOTria should go in column `Tria Premium`

[image]

Also if values for CGL,CPL and EO is 0 then I don't need those columns.

I am able to perform simple UNPIVOT , but confused when need to bring more columns

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    QuoteGUID, CoverageType, Premium
FROM
    Align_EnvionmentalRating_PremiumHistory
UNPIVOT
    (Premium FOR CoverageType  IN (CGL, CPL, EO)) AS up
```

[image]

UPDATE: Adding more data

Columns: `Policy Number, Policy Effective Date, Annual Statement Line, Fees, Risk State` should stay the same. 
Columns: `CGL, CGLTria,CPL,CPLTria,EO,EOTria` should be `UNPIVOTED`

```
select top 3 [Policy Number],
[Policy Effective Date],
'17.1' as [Annual Statement Line],
CGL,
CGLTria,
CPL,
CPLTria,
EO,
EOTria,
Fees,
[Risk State]
from #Test
```

[image]

UPDATE:
Adding consumable data:

```
create table dbo.TestDate  ( 
                            PolicyNumber varchar(50), 
                            PolicyEffectiveDate datetime, 
                            AnnualStatementLine decimal(5,1), 
                            CGL money, 
                            CGLTria money, 
                            CPL money,
                            CPLTria money,
                            EO money,
                            EOTria money,
                            Fees money,
                            RiskState varchar(2)
                            )
INSERT INTO dbo.TestDate (PolicyNumber, PolicyEffectiveDate , AnnualStatementLine, CGL , CGLTria , CPL ,CPLTria ,EO ,EOTria ,Fees ,RiskState )
values                          ('ENV560000001-00','2018-01-11 23:21:00',17.1,2000,160,674,54,341,0,250,'TX'),
                                ('ENV560000002-00','2018-01-11 00:56:00',17.1,0,0,3238,259,0,0,250,'NV'),
                                ('ENV560000003-00','2018-01-12 01:10:00',17.1,0,0,6045,484,0,0,250,'ND'),
                                ('ENV560000004-00','2018-01-14 01:18:00',17.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'ND')
select * from dbo.TestDate
```

Comment: Use conditional aggregation instead. If you can post some consumable data I will be happy to help.

Comment: #Sean I will post data in a couple of minutes. Thanks

Comment: #Sean I updated question. In real life there are many more columns that need to stay as is and some need to be UNPIVOTed.   Thanks

Comment: By consumable I meant something I can use to query with, not a picture. I don't want to spend a lot of time typing up this sample data from a picture. You should post ddl (create table statement) and sample data (insert statements). That way the people helping you can focus their effort on the problem, not setting up the problem.

Comment: Oh, got it. Sorry about that. Consumable data added. Thanks

Comment: To be honest the best approach to this is the one posted by tysonwright. Does it suck for the developer? Yes. Does it suck for performance? Yes. This is why you should use properly normalized data structures.

Comment: Thanks. Im thinking about to unpivot all columns I need in a temp table, then use inner join to join with data that do not need to be unpivoted.

Answer (score 2):

Below query should work.

`Select * From
(select top 3 QuoteGUID, CoverageType, Premium
from Align_EnvionmentalRating_PremiumHistory
unpivot
(
Premium for CoverageType  in ( CGL,CPL,EO)
) as up 
) A

INNER JOIN

(select top 3 QuoteGUID, CoverageType, Premium
from Align_EnvionmentalRating_PremiumHistory
unpivot
(
TriaPremium for  CoverageType in ( CGLTria,CPLTria,EOTria)
) as up
) as B

ON A.QuoteGUID=B.QuoteGUID AND A.CoverageType=substring(B.CoverageType,1,Len(B.CoverageType)-4)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but you could do this with simple UNION queries like this:

```
SELECT
    ID  =   a1.ID,
    CoverageType    =   'CGL',
    Premium =   a1.CGL,
    TriaPremium =   a1.CGLTria
FROM
     Align_EnvionmentalRating_PremiumHistory AS a1
WHERE
    a1.CGL <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ID  =   a2.ID,
    CoverageType    =   'CPL',
    Premium =   a2.CPL,
    TriaPremium =   a2.CPLTria
FROM
     Align_EnvionmentalRating_PremiumHistory AS a2
WHERE
    a2.CPL <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ID  =   a3.ID,
    CoverageType    =   'EO',
    Premium =   a3.EO,
    TriaPremium =   a3.EOTria
FROM
     Align_EnvionmentalRating_PremiumHistory AS a3
WHERE
    a3.EO <> 0
```

Comment: #tysonwright Thank you for your respond. In real life my dataset consist of   around 60 columns that need to stay  as is and 20 columns that need to be UNPIVOTed. UNION ALL is a great way to go but it will be too resource intensive. I will post data sample in a couple of minutes

Comment: What you might do then is to use this approach to unpivot to the 20 or so columns in a cte and then join to the main table again via the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

This produces the exact output you state you want from the sample data provided. It could get kind of nasty with as many as 60 columns you have to normalize but it should be a one time thing to write it. Having worked through this a bit it seems you really need to separate this into at least two tables but is a whole can of worms.

```
with NormalizedData
(
    PolicyNumber
    , CoverageType
    , Premium
    , TriaPremium
) as
(
    SELECT PolicyNumber
        , 'CGL'
        , CGL
        , CGLTria
    FROM TestDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT PolicyNumber
        , 'CPL'
        , CPL
        , CPLTria
    FROM TestDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT PolicyNumber
        , 'EO'
        , EO
        , EOTria
    FROM TestDate
)

select td.PolicyNumber
    , td.PolicyEffectiveDate
    , td.AnnualStatementLine
    , nd.CoverageType
    , nd.Premium
    , nd.TriaPremium
    , td.RiskState
from TestDate td
join NormalizedData nd on nd.PolicyNumber = td.PolicyNumber
order by td.PolicyNumber
    , nd.CoverageType
```

Answer (score 0):

I used CROSS APPLY operator to UNPIVOT the data, then included UNPIVOT statement in the INNER JOIN. That gave me desirable outcome.

```
declare @TestDate table  ( 
                            QuoteGUID varchar(8000), 
                            CGL money, 
                            CGLTria money, 
                            CPL money,
                            CPLTria money,
                            EO money,
                            EOTria money
                            )
INSERT INTO @TestDate (QuoteGUID,   CGL , CGLTria , CPL ,CPLTria ,EO ,EOTria  )
values                          ('2D62B895-92B7-4A76-86AF-00138C5C8540',2000,160,674,54,341,0),
                                ('BE7F9483-174F-4238-8931-00D09F99F398',0,0,3238,259,0,0),
                                ('BECFB9D8-D668-4C06-9971-0108A15E1EC2',0,0,0,0,0,0)

        select A.QuoteGUID
      ,B.*
 From  @TestDate A
 Cross Apply ( values ('CGL',CGL,CGLTria)
                     ,('CPL',CPL,CPLTria)
                     ,('CPL',EO,EOTria)
             ) B (CoverageType,Premium,TiraPremium)
```